# Does having relational tables affect the performance/scalability when using TimescaleDB?

Tags: database, time-series, partitioning, timescaledb

The chunk partitioning for hypertables is a key feature of TimescaleDB.
You can also create relational tables instead of hypertables, but without the chunk partitioning.

So if you have a database with around 5 relational tables and 1 hypertable, does it lose the performance and scalability advantage of chunk partitioning?

Comment: I think you're not losing but slowly adopting the partitioning on hypertables.

You can use a [partitioning_func](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hypertable/create_hypertable/#sample-usage) argument directly in the hypertable if you want to have a different partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the key advantages of TimescaleDB in comparison to other timeseries products is that timeseries data and relational data can be stored in the same database and then queried and joined together. So, "by design", it is expected that the database with several normal tables and hypertable will perform well. Usual PostgreSQL consideration about tables and other database objects, e.g., how shared memory is going to be affected, applies here.